# Unable to execute stored procedure to insert into table on linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table A on Server A which has a set of columns of user data. I need to insert this into table B on Server B. I've written a stored procedure to run this insert statement every night (SQL below). If I select and execute any part of the procedure, then it works fine, but if I attempt to execute the procedure as a whole, then it gives me an error:

> *The object name ServerB.DatabaseB.dbo.TableB has more than the maximum number of prefixes. The 
>   maximum is 2.*

T-SQL statement:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SERVERA.DatabaseA.dbo.TableA)
BEGIN
 TRUNCATE TABLE SERVERB.DatabaseB.dbo.TableB
 INSERT INTO 
    SERVERB.DatabaseB.dbo.TableB
 SELECT 
   Firstname,
   Surname,
   Username
 FROM 
   SERVERA.DatabaseA.dbo.TableA
END
```

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: I would check that your linked server (/permissions) works for the runtime user. In management studio can the executing user select from SERVERB.DatabaseB.dbo.TableB

Comment: How about posting the entire sproc code? You wouldn't happen to have a WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER in there, would you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of the `TRUNCATE TABLE` command, [as per the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx), is this:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE 
    [ { database_name .[ schema_name ] . | schema_name . } ]
    table_name
[ ; ]
```

As you can see, this command only supports names consisting of no more than three components, i.e. you can't specify a linked server name with `TRUNCATE TABLE`.

One solution could be to use a remote call to `sp_executesql`, like this:

```
EXECUTE SERVERB.DatabaseB.sys.sp_executesql N'TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.TableB';
```